# How to convert HTML to JSON

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get user input from a form to update onto a webpage. I have recently found out that JSON.stringify does not take html ID elements and that in order to do so they would need to be converted. I have found a guide here but did not help. If anyone has any ideas please let me know, I would truly appreciate it :D

[image: The form]

```js
   

 let type = document.getElementById('Type');
    let html = type.outerHTML;
    let typeData = {
      html: html
    };

    let name = document.getElementById('Name');
    let html = name.outerHTML;
    let nameData = {
      html: html
    };

    let quantity = document.getElementById('quantity');
    let html = quantity.outerHTML;
    let quanData = {
      html: html
    };



    update.addEventListener('click', _ => {
      fetch('/Plants', {
          method: 'put',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            type: typeData,
            name: nameData,
            quantity: quanData
          })
        })
        .then(res => {
          if (res.ok) return res.json()
        })
        .then(response => {
          window.location.reload(true)
        })
    })

server.js file where all my put route is

  app.put('/Plants', (req, res) => {
    quoteCollection.findOneAndUpdate(
      { type: req.body.type },
      {
        $set: {
          quantity: req.body.quantity,
          type: req.body.type,
          name: req.body.name
        }
      }
    )
    .then(result => {res.json('Success')})
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
  });
});
```

```html
    <h2>Update an item</h2>
    <form id="inventory-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Type" name="Type" id="Type" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="Name" id="Name" />
      <input type="number" placeholder="quantity" name="quantity" id="quantity" />
      <button id="update-button " type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: All you should really need is the `value` of each of those `<input>` elements....not the html

Comment: Your code is not valid. Fix the console errors and remove the space in the ID of the button

Answer (score 0):

Use formData and do not use the click event but the form submit event:

```js
document.getElementById("inventory-form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(this);
  fetch('/Plants', {
      method: 'put',
      body: formData
    })
    .then(res => {
      if (res.ok) return res.json()
    })
    .then(response => {
      //    window.location.reload(true) // WHY???
    })

})
```

```html
<h2>Update an item</h2>
<form id="inventory-form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Type" name="Type" id="Type" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="Name" id="Name" />
  <input type="number" placeholder="quantity" name="quantity" id="quantity" />
  <button id="update-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

But WHY reload the page?

Or if you need to refresh WHY use fetch?